# A Simple Patttern

Tags: code-golf, string

**Inputs:**

Two single digits (let's call them `m` and `n`) and two chars (let's call them `a` and `b`) in your input format of choice.

**Output:**

For the walkthrough, pretend `m=2, n=5, a='a', b='b'`.

Your output will be a string built from your four inputs. Let's call the string `result`, with value `""`. First, concatenate `a` onto `result` `m` times, so concatenate `a` onto `result` `2` times. `result` now equals `aa`. Second, concatenate `b` onto `result` `m` times, so concatenate `b` onto `result` `2` times. `result` now equals `aabb`. Lastly, if result is already longer than `n`, truncate `result` so that it has length `n`. Otherwise, continue alternating with `m` length runs of `a` and `b` until `result` has length `n`. The final `result` is `aabba`, which has length `5`.

**Test Cases:**

```
Input: m = 2, n = 4, a = A, b = B

Output: AABB

Input: m = 3, n = 8, a = A, b = B

Output: AAABBBAA

Input: m = 4, n = 3, a = A, b = B

Output: AAA

Input: m = 2, n = 10, a = A, b = B

Output: AABBAABBAA
```

As all knows, lesser one will rule the world, so the smallest programs, in bytes, win! :)

Comment: What do you mean by "total char in output will be 'n'" and "lesser one will rule the world"?

Comment: I basically rewrote the challenge, keeping what I believe was your original intent. You can rollback if you want, but in its original state it's not going to get reopened.

Comment: @StepHen you saved my day:p gracias :)

Comment: @Durga no problem :) I'm glad it still says what you wanted.

Comment: @Durga proposed test case : `m=2,n=10,a=A,b=B`

Comment: ^ That test case is important.  Do you want it to be AABBAAAAAAA or AABBAABBAA?

Comment: @NathanMerrill agreed, my edit assumes the first, the second is more logical though.

Comment: @Rod output will be AABBAABBAA, as mentioned in case 2

Comment: @StepHen output will AABBAABBAA what Rod asked

Comment: are we guaranteed that `m,n>0`?

Comment: @Giuseppe yes :)

Answer (score 8):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/), 32 bytes

```python
lambda m,n,a,b:((a*m+b*m)*n)[:n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P802JzE3KSVRIVcnTydRJ8lKQyNRK1c7SStXUytPM9oqL/Z/QVFmXolGmoaRjoKJjoK6ozqQcFLX1OSCSRjrKFhglQAqN0aW@A8A)

Comment: Anonymous functions are allowed last I checked so you can remove the `f=` for -2 bytes.

Comment: @ComradeSparklePony: Thanks for the heads up. That was leftover from the TiO; I'd actually already removed it from the byte count.

Comment: You can put the `f=` in the header section of TIO, so you don't need to remove it manually. [TIO](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSFXJ08nUSfJSkMjUStXO0krV1MrTzPaKi/2f0FRZl6JRpqGkY6CiY6CuqM6kHBS19TkgkkY6yhYYJUAKjdGlvgPAA)

Comment: Ah, I always forget about backslashes. Thanks.

Comment: To whoever suggested editing `(a*m+b*m)` -> `(a+b)*m`: this does not work.

Answer (score 6):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 5 bytes

```
Y"i:)
```

Inputs are a string with the two characters, then `m`, then `n`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/P1Ip00rz/391Ryd1LmMuCwA)

#### Explanation

```
Y"   % Implicit inputs: string and number m. Apply run-length decoding.
     % The second input is reused for each char in the first. Gives a
     % string
i    % Input number n
:    % Push vector [1 2 ... n]
)    % Index the string with the numbers in that vector. Indexing is
     % modular, so the chars are reused if necessary. Implicit display
```

Answer (score 5):

### Haskell, <s>44</s> 40 bytes

```
f=(.cycle).take
(n#m)a=f n.(f m a++).f m
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcYxDoAgDAXQ3VP8FAcICYuLC4PepDEQCdAYZfH01Te9k5@aWlPN0YbjPVpyYXBNkxXTHccMCTajg7134Y92LoKI6y4yMAN2NYsDbQTaCfoB)

Answer (score 5):

## Ruby, 29 characters

```ruby
->m,n,a,b{((a*m+b*m)*n)[0,n]}
```

Sample run:

```
irb(main):001:0> ->m,n,a,b{((a*m+b*m)*n)[0,n]}[3, 8, 'A', 'B']
=> "AAABBBAA"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY/LDoIwEEXX9CtmQwo4GAQXbmpSfqPpAgSiiRTCY2HEb6@t1hh142pm7rnzGubyohtgOt63qLDA8hoERdSuyqgNIxWKBJW86X6eRqB@nCYjLODHm884UvBB0JPqKQLt5smGoR7n8@QEYAycIAkRxBMiRdgayK0jp9KmPLeJhRnC7hsamnPuDKY1@zFYJtd1cThC1cFi7kEwyxfiPXcDg0ZERpbE@@ul1wR0xz@K9y@S1KrSdw)

Answer (score 5):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 10 bytes

```
VîUçW +UçX
```

First try using a golfing language. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/P@zwutDDy8MVtIFkxP//xlyGBlxKjkpcSk5KAA)

### Explanation

```
Vî          // repeat the following until it reaches length V (second input)
  UçW       // third input repeated U (first input) times
      +UçX  // plus the fourth input, repeated U times
```

Comment: Thanks for using Japt, and well done :-) You could do `VîWpU +XpU` too, but both do the same thing. `Vî` is perfect for this challenge.

Comment: @ETHproductions Thanks, and thanks for making it! I really enjoy how everything transpiles nicely to JS code.

Answer (score 3):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 13 bytes

```
ÀäjÀäêÍî
À|lD
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v//3DD4SVZIOLwqsO9h9dxHW6oyXH5/z@RK@m/8X8TAA)

`a` and `b` are taken on separate lines in the input, `m` and `n` are taken as argument, reversed (so `n` is the first argument and `m` is the second)

#### Explanation

```
Àäj      ' duplicate the inputs [arg 1] times
a -> a
b    b
     a
     b
     ...
   Àäê   ' duplicate everything straight down [arg 2] times - À cycles arguments
a -> aaa
b    bbb
a    aaa
b    bbb
...  ...
      Íî ' remove all newlines
-> aaabbbaaabbb...
À|lD     ' delete from the [arg 1] + 1 column onwards
-> aaabbbaa
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>6</s> 4 bytes

```
xFṁ⁵
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/7/C7eHOxkeNW////x@t7qiuo6DupB773@i/oQEA)

Thanks to [Jonathan Allan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/53748/jonathan-allan) for better input format (-2).

Comment: 4 bytes as a full program [with a different input format](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/7/C7eHOxkeNW////x@t7qiuo6DupB773@i/oQEA)

Comment: @JonathanAllan Heh I usually try to avoid using the third argument but this time it makes my answer way shorter.

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>41</s> 39 bytes

```r
function(d,m,n)cat(d[gl(2,m,n)],sep='')
```

An anonymous function; prints the result to stdout. Takes the characters as a vector `d=c(a,b)`. `gl` generates factors (integers) of (in this case) `2` levels of run length `m` with total length `n`! `cat` concatenates and prints them as a string.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP08jRSdXJ08zObFEIyU6PUfDCMyN1SlOLbBVV9f8n6aRrKGeqK6jnqSuqWOkY2ig@R8A)

Comment: I think `function(d,m,n)rep(d,e=m,l=n)` would be a valid submission.

Comment: @ovs unfortunately `rep` will result in a vector of characters rather than a single string

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 bytes

```
×J×I£
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//8HSvw9M9Dy3@/z9a3VFdR91JPZbLmMsCAA)

**Explanation**

```
×      # repeat a and b m times each
 J     # join to string
  ×    # repeat the string n times
   I£  # take the first n characters
```

Comment: Exactly what I got without checking first :P

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>36</s> <s>35</s> 29 bytes

Yet another Haskell solution (expects the characters given as a list):

```hs
(m#n)c=take n$cycle$c<*[1..m]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY/LCsIwEEX3@YpLdZHIUHwtXJhF6tovEJEQA5Y2aUkGxK@vreJjMYs5Z7jDvdnc@LYd6tB3iXHoIqeuLY9dtFdIBNsfL1CDDLOonGbbeMS5e7jWz91@cVqVZTgP7DMfbPYZWgAnyDVhS4WpCkJhTFUVauQEuSHsfnwUlTEftyVs/twHr2m1/I96z8uehZg@QwaK5DIlBf1dmBIlrXk6vN988uCXHXvAZQgRbB1H8m4o@1RHLqc4hW@d4Qk)

Thanks @Laikoni for -1 byte.

Comment: You can save a byte with `(m#n)a b=`.

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript, 55 bytes

```js
(m,n,a,b)=>(a[r='repeat'](m)+b[r](m))[r](n).substr(0,n)
```

Example code snippet:

```js
f=

(m,n,a,b)=>(a[r='repeat'](m)+b[r](m))[r](n).substr(0,n)

console.log(f(2, 4, 'A', 'B'))
console.log(f(3, 8, 'A', 'B'))
console.log(f(4, 3, 'A', 'B'))
console.log(f(2, 9, 'A', 'B'))
```

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript, 53 bytes

```
(m,n,a,b)=>a.repeat(n).replace(/./g,(i,j)=>j/m&1?b:i)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 3 bytes

Direct Port of my Haskell answer, except that the argument order is different:

```
↑¢Ṙ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//1HbxEOLHu6c8f//f@P/So5OSv8tAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>48</s> 43 bytes

```hs
(m#n)a|r<-(<$[1..m])=take n.cycle.(r a++).r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/XyNXOU8zsabIRlfDRiXaUE8vN1bTtiQxO1UhTy@5MjknVU@jSCFRW1tTr@h/bmJmnoKtQkq@QkFRZl6JgoqChpGCsoKJpoK6o7qCupM6lwIcwFUYA1VY4FVhAlRhDFfxHwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), <s>37</s> 27 bytes

```
[:|G=;+G+;][:|G=G+G]?_sG,d
```

### Explanation

```
          This takes its arguments as frequency m, A, B, length n
          For example: 2, A, B, 8
 :        Read a cmd line arg as number 'b' ('a' is used by the FOR declaration as loop counter)
[ |       Start a FOR loop, from 1 to b
G=  G     Set G to hold itself
  ;+      prepended by a cmd line arg read as strig and assigned to A$
     +;   and followed by a cmd line arg read as strig and assigned to B$
]         At the end of the FOR loop, G has had A added to the front twice, and B t the end x2: G$ = AABB
[:|       FOR c = 1 to n
G=G+G]      Add G to itself          G$ = AABBAABBAABBAABBAABBAABBAABBAABB
?_sG,d    PRINT the first n chars of G$   AABBAABB
```

---

Previous attempt:

```
(37b)  {Z=Z+;┘_LZ|~a=:|_X]~a%:|\C=A┘A=;┘B=C
Takes its arguments as `A, length n, frequency m, B`.
Basically adds A to Z until length % freq = 0, then swaps A for B. Loops until lengtn = n
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP>=7.1, 77 bytes

```php
for([,$x,$l,$f,$s]=$argv;$l-=$z;)echo str_repeat(++$i&1?$f:$s,$z=min($l,$x));
```

[PHP Sandbox Online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f0243b1f9a55bba841671ca2fca5f4e9aaaca95a)

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), 75 bytes

```java
void f(int m,int n,char[]s){for(int i=0;i<n;)System.out.print(s[i++/m%2]);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pY2xDoIwFEVn@AoW0zZURGAwqQ66OzEShoqARSikLRhD@HYsGBcSJ5b3knffuaegHd3WTcqL@3Ns2lvJEispqZTWlTLej13N7lYGGVdWhafJcfKgIool6rNazAE7uYQdOUHhW6q0cupWOY3QCZQRs@1dtfFiRIZfvVRU6TU3V1oCQ6Wf8yimItetpsHT12yHyMmghwM8Hb7WHpwBBhcwIGIaS12pCbLAfXxYgwfYX4N7eO/@4QdzGD8)

Answer (score 1):

## [Cubix](https://github.com/ETHproductions/cubix), <s>63</s> 58 bytes

```
.rr.@u:s?.\.sw).i|>v:.\nB;?(q:Is...;rr/s.uw/....sIB/\/?(qo
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy5Nyqz4/1@vqEjPodSq2F4vRq@4XFMvs8auzEovJs/J2l6j0MqzWE9Pz7qoSL9Yr7RcH8jWK/Z00o/RB8rl//@fmKRjrGNoAAA)

[watch the interpreter](http://ethproductions.github.io/cubix/?code=ICAgICAgICAuIHIgciAuCiAgICAgICAgQCB1IDogcwogICAgICAgID8gLiBcIC4KICAgICAgICBzIHcgKSAuCmkgfCA+IHYgOiAuIFwgbiBCIDsgPyAoIHEgOiBJIHMKLiAuIC4gOyByIHIgLyBzIC4gdSB3IC8gLiAuIC4gLgpzIEkgQiAvIFwgLyA/ICggcSBvIC4gLiAuIC4gLiAuCi4gLiAuIC4gLiAuIC4gLiAuIC4gLiAuIC4gLiAuIC4KICAgICAgICAuIC4gLiAuCiAgICAgICAgLiAuIC4gLgogICAgICAgIC4gLiAuIC4KICAgICAgICAuIC4gLiAuCg==&input=YWIsMywxMA==&speed=10)

Takes input like `ab*m*n` where the `*` can be any non-digit character.

Cube version:

```
        . r r .
        @ u : s
        ? . \ .
        s w ) .
i | > v : . \ n B ; ? ( q : I s
. . . ; r r / s . u w / . . . .
s I B / \ / ? ( q o . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
        . . . .
        . . . .
        . . . .
        . . . .
```

- `i|is` : read in the chars, and swap them (so `a` is on top)
- `I:q` : read in `m`, dup, and push to bottom (stack is now `m,b,a,m`)
- `)` : decrement
- `?` : turn right if positive, go straight if zero (duplicates `a`)
- positive branch (loop)

  - `s:rur(/w` : swap, dup, move `m-i` to the top of the stack, decrement `m-i`
- zero branch

  - `B` : reverse stack (which now has `m` copies of `a`: `a... b m`)
  - `n` : negate `m` (so we can use `?` to turn left)
  - `)` : increment
  - `?` : go straight if zero, turn left if negative
- negative branch  (duplicates `b`)

  - `s:r\/rw)\` basically the same as the positive branch but with increment and left turns.
- zero branch (prints the output)

  - `>v;` : pop the `0` off the stack (looks like `a...b...`)
  - `/B` : reverse the stack
  - `I` : read `n`
  - `s` : swap
    print loop:
- `oq` : print and push to bottom of stack now looks like: `ab...a...n`
- `(` decrement `n`
- `?` : turn right if positive, go straight if zero
- If right, : `/su` : swap top of stack and continue the loop
- if zero, `/` reflects down and the code evaluated is `Iru@`; `@` terminates the program.

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 10 bytes

```
…⁺×ζＩθ×εＮＮ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM3PydFwzElRSMkMze1WKNKR8E5sbhEo1BTU0cBIpSqo@CZV1Ba4leam5RapKGpqYnOt/7/34jL0IDLkcvpv27Zf93iHAA) Link is to verbose version of code and includes fourth example. (Annoyingly the deverbosifer won't remove the separator if I add one before the last `InputNumber()`.)

Comment: What do you mean by the separator? (Can you give an example)

Comment: @ASCII-only With the comma before the last InputNumber(),  notice that the generated code has an unnecessary separator: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM3PydFwzElRSMkMze1WKNKR8E5sbhEo1BTU0cBIpSqo@CZV1Ba4leam5RapKEJkkETsP7/34jL0IDLkcvpv27Zf93iHAA "Charcoal – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica , 61 bytes

```
T=Table;StringTake[""<>Flatten@T[{#3~T~#,#4~T~#},⌈#2/#⌉],#2]&
```

**input**

> [2,10,"A","B"]

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 44 bytes

```
StringPadRight[x={##3}~Table~#<>"",#2,x]&
```

## Explanation

`` is the three byte private use character `U+F3C7`, representing the postfix `\[Transpose]` operator in Mathematica. No TIO link because [Mathics](https://mathics.github.io/) does not support ``, `\[Transpose]` has the wrong operator precedence, the second argument to `Table` is required to be a list, and most importantly, `StringPadRight` is not implemented.

```
                                         & (* Function *)
                 {##3}                     (* which takes the third and fourth arguments *)
                      ~Table~#             (* repeats them a number of times equal to the first argument *)
                                          (* takes the tranpose *)
                               <>""        (* then joins the strings with the empty string *)
               x=                          (* sets x equal to that string *)
StringPadRight[                            (* then pads x *)
                                   ,#2     (* to a length equal to the second argument *)
                                      ,x]  (* with x. *)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 5 bytes

```apl
⎕⍴⎕/⎕
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKMdSPRNfdS7BUjqAzFI6H86l3pikjqXEZehAQA)

Takes the two chars in a string as the first input, followed by `m` and then `n`.

#### Explanation

Let the example input be `'ab'`, `2`, `10`.

```apl
⎕/⎕                 Replicate the two-char string `m` times
                    2/'ab' => 'aabb'
⎕⍴                  Shape it so that its length is `n`
                    10⍴'aabb' => 'aabbaabbaa'
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 13 bytes

```
KE<*+*EQ*EQKK
```

[Try it online!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=KE%3C%2A%2B%2AEQ%2AEQKK&input=2%0A10%0A%22A%22%0A%22B%22&debug=0)

**Explanation**

```
                 # Implicitly store m to Q
KE               # Store n to K
     *EQ         # Perform a * m
        *EQ      # Perform b * m
    +            # Concatenate the two strings
   *       K     # Multiply by n
  <         K    # Take the first n characters of the string
```

Answer (score 0):

## k, 10 bytes

```
{y#,/x#'z}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/P82qulJZR79CWb2q9n@anrqGhpG1ibWSo5OSJpeGsbUFjGlibQxjGlkbGkDZmv8B)

Answer (score 0):

## [Chip](https://github.com/Phlarx/chip), 588 bytes

```
*Z~vZ.*ZZZs  z. z. z. z. z. z. z. z.
  ,'|`-. ZZ--#<,#<,#<,#<,#<,#<,#<,#<
a/mAM/a| `~S `x'`x'`x'`x'`x'`x'`x'`x.
b/mBM/b|  *.)/')/')/')/')/')/')/')/'|
c/mCM/cZv--x^x-^x-^x-^x-^x-^x-^x-^x-'
d/mDM/d||A~#M',-',-',-',-',-',-',-'
e/mEM/e||B~#M-',-',-',-',-',-',-'
f/mFM/f||C~#M--',-',-',-',-',-'
g/mGM/g||D~#M---',-',-',-',-'
h/mHM/h||E~#M----',-',-',-'
 `v~v' ||F~#M-----',-',-'
* `mz  ||G~#M------',-'
Z  `---x'H~#M-------'
Z,--z--^----'
Z|z. z. z. z. z. z. z. z.
Zx#<,#<,#<,#<,#<,#<,#<,#<
 |`x'`x'`x'`x'`x'`x'`x'`xT
 |A| B| C| D| E| F| G| H|
 )\')\')\')\')\')\')\')\'
 `--^--^--^--^--^--^--'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZG7asQwFETr6CsubCHWWL6QOo3Xz0ZVUolgZHsfTiEIBIwxg3/dsbObJWRlOMXVnCkE03Yfn/McmKk3UWCM@SIaIy@CKJSwKiJjlNq9hD5EzS7WXIPs9Ep2kD4i0bA7aG5AFER7ll4gWnaJ5tb0Sg3VoLxIcWSXaj4C8bTTMlQexIldpvkEHJaOt3Fml2s@A8naePQXdoXmC5D@@H@2Y1dq7oDsav86sv3USwLym7ubgKwbaTHFr7nmhsgu9yDLe76moVKjUtXtha2ZzLC1DWFjkLdFxaADKAGloAyUgwpQCUH7d@lFrJ@sHpDzXDdPz98)

Takes input as a 4-character string. The first two are the characters *a* and *b*, followed by the byte value *m*, and then the byte value *n*. For example, the TIO includes input `ab<tab>2`, this corresponds to 'a', 'b', 9, 50. (Since the codes for `<tab>` and `2` are 9 and 50.

#### How?

This answer is a bit of a behemoth, but here's the highlights:

The upper left block, with the lowercase `a`-`h`, is the storage mechanism for the characters *a* and *b*, one line per bit. At its bottom, with the `v~v` and `mz` is the switching mechanism, to swap between the two.

In the middle is a column with a bunch of `~#M`'s. This reads in *m* and stores its negative. The big triangle to the right is just wires to bring this value into the upper accumulator.

The upper right block is the accumulator for *m*. It increments every cycle (starting from *-m*) until it reaches zero. When this happens, the output character is swapped, and counting restarts from *-m*.

Meanwhile, there is the lower block, which is the *n* accumulator. Since *n* is only read once, we don't need a bank of memory (`M` and `m`) to store this value. We simply negate it and start counting. When this value reaches zero, the whole shebang is simply terminated.

All the other guff is delays (`Z` and `z`), wiring (`-`, `|`, ...), and other miscellany.